# How to run the httpd daemon process for apache, in background in windows?

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-services, daemon

I downloaded httpd-2.4.23-x64-vc14, unzipped, changed some configurations in httpd.conf and now when I run httpd.exe, my localhost runs fine, but I don't want to keep seeing that command prompt, and go and start it again everytime I shutdown my system. How to make it act like a service, which automatically starts everytime I start my machine.

Comment: You downloaded mySQL and installed Apache? Hmm. On your question - have you even tried google? This comes as a first result: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Running Apache as a Windows Service

Apache comes with a utility called the Apache Service Monitor. With it you can see and manage the state of all installed Apache services on any machine on your network. To be able to manage an Apache service with the monitor, you have to first install the service (either automatically via the installation or manually).

You can install Apache as a Windows NT service as follows from the command prompt at the Apache bin subdirectory:

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

You will have to do this using a Windows Account that is allowed to register sevices, *probably an Administrator account.*

> Shamelessly RIPPED OFF from of all the strange places [**THE MANUAL**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html)
>
> Go figure.... who would have thought of looking there!

Then check with the windows services monitor

```
WindowsKey+R
services.msc
```

that `Apache` is set to `Startup Type = Auto` so that it starts as part of a boot

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the taunt :P, I had indeed seen the manual but didn't understand it right, thought, "httpd.exe -k install" needs an argument as the service name I want to install.

Comment: You only need to add a service name if you want to change its name from `Apache` to `SomethingElse`